# In MVC3, I get a "Conditional compilation is turned off" warning when outputting Model variable into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, razor, compiler-warnings

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor. Here is the code causing the warning:

```
var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.Latitude, @Model.Longitude);
```

The code works fine when it runs, but I'd like to get ride of the warnings.

**Edit**

Here's more of the surrounding code:

```
    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.Latitude, @Model.Longitude);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: userLocation
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }
```

If I add parenthesis like so:

```
var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(@(Model.Latitude), @(Model.Longitude));
```

I get a new warning, "Invalid character."

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in the line you have provided it simply causes the warning based on an error outside of the code you have provided.

In general this is a js error that has nothing todo with Razor or VS, but often is caused by missing parenthesis or s quotations. Can you share the surrounding code?

Comment: sry if I was not clear, there are no parenthesis missing within the line you provided the error is outside of the line. The extended code you provide shows that an error seems to appear as soon as you use razor syntax, this is a clear sign that somewhere before that there is an error in your html/js can you provide the entire code junk, including script tags?